# Should create new RethinkDB connection for every query?

Tags: java, rethinkdb

Java + RethinkDB.
Should we create new RethinkDB connection for each query and then close the connection?
Or just create one creation and use it for all the queries?
What should be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

The best performance is a `single` connection/pool, but is more difficult approaching depending of our language/architecture.